# Can I visit Poveglia island in Venice lagoon?

Tags: photography, venice

I would like to visit Poveglia plague island in Venice lagoon to take some pictures and get in touch with its grim and dark atmosphere. But recently on website [atlasobscura.com](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/poveglia-plague-island) there was in information that

> Poveglia remains for now strictly off-limits to visitors.

So my question is "is it possible to get to the island nowadays"? By hiring water taxi, for example.

Answer (score -2):

I am not completely sure, but I believe it will remain closed until someone agrees to the government requirements for a lease.  As of June 2014, that had not happened.  [This article](http://espresso.repubblica.it/attualita/2014/06/11/news/l-isola-che-non-c-e-resta-pubblica-per-ora-il-gioiello-della-laguna-non-sara-svenduto-1.168897) provides some details.  For English, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poveglia) (but it has not quite as many details).  Neither one, however, told me what is the status THIS year.

As for being "off-limits," I don't know whether that is a legal matter or just a matter of [availability of transportation](http://mentalfloss.com/article/24658/strange-geographies-happy-haunted-island-poveglia),

So, to answer your question *as written*, Yes, you can go there.  But if you really meant "will I get in trouble?" then I don't know.